# For loop limit 1 - idiomatic apex?

Tags: apex, soql

I came across this today:

```
for(custom__c custom: [SELECT field__c FROM custom LIMIT 1]){
    \\record processing goes here
}
```

At first this confused me since it seems strange to have a for loop when you can only ever have one record. On the other hand, I can see why this might be preferred to doing an explicit null check on the result of the query.

Is this the generally preferred idiomatic way to process a single record from a soql query?

Comment: Any answer would be opinion based.

Comment: It's often a good way to go in my opinion. Handles zero or one records and doesn't leave a list variable in scope for any following code. If it is new to your codebase, comment it to start with.

Answer (score 2):

this concept is  called [SOQL For Loops](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_loops_for_SOQL.htm).  The main idea here is using [queryMore()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_querymore.htm)  by saving `queryLocator` to retrieve another chunk of records and not to store them in a heap.  Pay attention, that you can use soql for loop only for objects, that supports `queryMore` call.

You have to use soql for loop in cases when you don't need to store selected records in heap and avoid heap size limit.

According to your example, there is no need to use this construction, as you are processing only one record. You can use:

```
Custom__c custom  = [SELECT field__c FROM custom LIMIT 1];
```

Will throw an exception, if no record to select.

---

```
List<Custom__c> custom  = [SELECT field__c FROM custom LIMIT 1];
```

will not throw an exception if no records to select,  will return an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing would be to have a selector layer that you call from wherever you need it and gives you exactly what you need. In this case one record.
Example:

```
public with sharing class AccountSelector {

    public static Account ById (List<String> queryFields, String accountId) {
        List<Account> result =
                Database.query('SELECT  ' + String.join(queryFields, ', ')
                             + '  FROM  Account'
                             + ' WHERE  Id =: accountId'
                             + ' LIMIT  1');

        return result.isEmpty() ? null : result[0];
    }
}
```

Then you would just have to:

```
Account acc = AccountSelector.ById(new String[]{'Id', 'Name'}, 'XXXXXXXX');

if(acc == null) return;

// logic
```